# Local push notifications not appearing on device?

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I have created a react native app for both android & iOS which utilises the react-native-push-notification package for local push notifications.

I have a lot of difficulty in replicating the notifications in iOS. I initially had a RCTPushNotificationIOS error which I resolved by reviewing this post here.

I'm using RN 0.60

From my understanding, the following should do the trick. Manually linking the RCTPushNotification library should not be required if I update the pod file.

I added the following line to pod file

```
pod 'React-RCTPushNotification', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/PushNotificationIOS'
```

I'm able to add

```
#import <React/RCTPushNotificationManager.h>
```

to my AppDelegate.m with no errors and then run 'pod install' in the iOS folder

The app builds successfully (After cleaning) with this combination. 
I debug the app on my physical device (iPhone 6s) when running through Xcode.

This is a basic demo app I built to try and test a basic local notification

```
var PushNotification = require('react-native-push-notification');

const App = () => {

  PushNotification.configure({
      // (required) Called when a remote or local notification is opened or received
      onNotification: function(notification) {
          console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );

          // required on iOS only (see fetchCompletionHandler docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html)
          notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);

      }
  });


  return (
      <View>
          <Button
              onPress={() => {
                Alert.alert('You tapped the button!');

                PushNotification.localNotification({
                    /* iOS and Android properties */
                    message: 'MESSAGE FROM NOTIFICATION'
                });
              }}
              title='Call function'
          />
      </View>
  );
};
```

When clicking on the button, I expect the alert to popup and then the notification to follow, however the alert pops up and no notification ever follows. Nothing logs to the console either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pod install
```

only links the native modules into your app. You must enable `notification` and `register` events as per the documentation:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html